# How to change the ball color every time it bounces off the wall?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I just saw this question **[ball bounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26676713/making-a-ball-to-bounce-when-a-button-is-clicked)** while searching for some JavaScript code. Its easy code but what to do if we want to change the color randomly of the ball every time it bounces off the wall.

**My thoughts:**

Have a random color generator and use it. Something like this

```
function get_random_color() {
    var letters = 'ABCDE'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i=0; i<3; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
    }
    return color;
}
```

But how to change the color of the ball. I tried `context.fill()` but no help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be as straight forward as calling the function when the ball hits a wall, like this

```
function myFunction() {
    var context;
    var dx = 4;
    var dy = 4;
    var y = 150;
    var x = 10;
    var color = get_random_color();

    function draw() {
        context = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
        context.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = color;
        context.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
        if (x < 0 || x > 400) {
            dx = -dx;
            color = get_random_color();
        }
        if (y < 0 || y > 300) {
            dy = -dy;
            color = get_random_color();
        }
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
    }
    setInterval(draw, 10);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/1gjyzp96/)

Comment: thanks. just before you post this I got it running . Found context.fillStyle property.